# Java - Why StringBuffer require base64 to get correct hex?

Tags: java, arrays, base64, byte, stringbuffer

e.g. this will get correct hex value 0x41 of 'A':

```
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    strBuf.append(toBase64("A".getBytes()));
    String ciphertext = strBuf.toString();
    byte[] encryted_bytes = ciphertext.getBytes();
    byte[] cipherBytes = fromBase64(new String(encryted_bytes));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : cipherBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
    }
    Log.d("hole", "hex:" + sb.toString());
```

But without base64, this get `5B 42 40 33 33 64 62 35 61 30`:

```
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    strBuf.append(("A".getBytes()));
    String ciphertext = strBuf.toString();
    byte[] encryted_bytes = ciphertext.getBytes();
    byte[] cipherBytes = new String(encryted_bytes).getBytes();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : cipherBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
    }
    Log.d("hole", "hex:" + sb.toString());
```

Method of base64:

```
public static String toBase64(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public static byte[] fromBase64(String base64) {
    return Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

What's the step of 2nd code generate `5B 42 40 33 33 64 62 35 61 30` ? And how base64 make it generate correct hex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial point in this is that there is no `StringBuffer.append(byte[])` method.

So what happens when calling `append` with a `byte[]`-argument? The JVM chooses the next best fit and that is `append(Object)` which per javadoc does the following:

> The overall effect is exactly as if the argument were converted to a string by the method String.valueOf(Object), and the characters of that string were then appended to this character sequence.

So it appens the String-representation of the `byte[]` which looks like

```
[B@33db5a0
```

The second approach correts this by using the Base64-representation of the byte array which is a `String` and thus the chosen method is `append(String)`.

As a general rule: always be aware where you are working with `byte`s and where with `char` or `String` and never use string-operations on byte-arrays.